# should i give min-height and max-height only in pixels for different size sizes?

Tags: html, css

Here is the example

```
<div id="parentContainer" style="height:100%;width:100%">
<div id="childContainer" style="height:98%";width:100%>
<div id="list" style="min-height:20%;max-height:90%;color:red;">
Hello, this contains the web page content
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

The question is that one of my co-worker said  things like margin, min-height and max-height must be given in pixels for a responsive design just  to make sure that the layout doesn't go haywire with various screen sizes and browsers , but my decision is that for layout that suits for various screen sizes giving css values in percentage is the right way to go because 20px may look larger if the resolution of the screen is lower but for higher resolution screens, it will not look as it expect it to see in the lower resolution screen. pls correct me if i'm wrong as i'm looking for the right approach.

Answer (score 1):

you can use percentage in `min|max-width` and `min|max-height`.

like this,

```
min-height: 100% !important; /* browser fill */
max-height: 100%; 
min-width: 100%; 
max-width: 100%;
```

for more info refer this,

[simple docs](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_dim_min-height.asp)

Comment: is there any specific scenario where px should be used?i do not use px anywhere in css, event for font-sizes i use vw for making the font-size responsive without a media query.

Comment: in image i used px if its layout, use percentage for browser fill... see this link https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_units.asp for css units (px,%, vw etc)

Answer (score 0):

The reason your colleague is suggesting pixels is that although it's a nice theory that specifying percentage sizes will make things scale and be laid out responsively, this doesn't work well in practice as the results are unpredictable. You have more control when using pixel sizes, and modern frameworks are designed to maintain containers at a fixed size. The main technique that gets used is to then essentially flow containers into 'rows' when the containers won't fit horizontally on the screen (and to show and hide different containers in certain cases).

Min height and max height are really for ensuring that the dimensions of any particular container are predictable, which can be for a variety of reasons (especially to ensure that elements don't become too large or too small when scaled), and this *may* form part of a responsive design strategy.

Look at Twitter bootstrap as a framework (especially the grid system https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/layout/grid/).

Also look at flexbox (a CSS technique). Here's a fun way to learn it -
 http://flexboxfroggy.com/

Comment: does using px apply to only max and min height or to everything? for ex: things like font-size, height, width etc. then if representing everything in pixels is the right option so in what scenarios the percentages are useful